# FABGL library esp32 arduino ide: Terminal.write error when using variables

Tags: c++, variables, mod-rewrite, arduino, esp32

Sorry for bother yours.

I was trying to do this:

```
Terminal.write("\e[" + String(bcor) +";" + String(fcor) + "m"); // background: defined, foreground: defined
Terminal.write("\e[" + String(vxx) + ";" + String(vyy) + "H");   // move cursor to x, y
```

Using variables in place of the constants, but this is impossible. I tried everything, but the Arduino esp32 compiler have the same error:
error: conversion from 'const uint8_t*' {aka 'const unsigned char*'} to 'const StringSumHelper' is ambiguous

```
 Terminal.write((const uint8_t*)"\e[" + String(bcor) +";" + String(fcor) + "m"); // background: black, foreground: green

mmsj300:313:53: error: conversion from 'uint8_t*' {aka 'unsigned char*'} to 'const StringSumHelper' is ambiguous
         Terminal.write((uint8_t*)"\e[" + String(bcor) +";" + String(fcor) + "m"); // background: defined, foreground: defined
```

I Have tried putting the (const uint8_t*) before the strings e etc, but nothing works... I see the implementation, but using (uint8_t*) also not working.

Can someone help me please ?

That cant be my fault, I need to know how to call the Terminal.write with variables, i do this in another's programs with another libraries all the times, and here are impossible..

PS: I have read all the examples, anyone have any consideration about use variables in the Terminal.write, only char (buf[i]), any time not have examples with strings variables.

Terminal.write definition:

```
size_t Terminal::write(const uint8_t * buffer, size_t size)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    write(*(buffer++));
  return size;
}
```

please help me.

Complete Error Message:

```
mmsj300:313:53: error: conversion from 'uint8_t*' {aka 'unsigned char*'} to 'const StringSumHelper' is ambiguous
         Terminal.write((uint8_t*)"\e[" + String(bcor) +";" + String(fcor) + "m"); // background: defined, foreground: defined
                                                     ^
In file included from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Arduino.h:165,
                 from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_152019\sketch\mmsj300.ino.cpp:1:
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:393:9: note: candidate: 'StringSumHelper::StringSumHelper(long long unsigned int)' <near match>
         StringSumHelper(unsigned long long num) :
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:393:9: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
mmsj300:313:24: error: invalid conversion from 'uint8_t*' {aka 'unsigned char*'} to 'long long unsigned int' [-fpermissive]
         Terminal.write((uint8_t*)"\e[" + String(bcor) +";" + String(fcor) + "m"); // background: defined, foreground: defined
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Arduino.h:165,
                 from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_152019\sketch\mmsj300.ino.cpp:1:
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:390:9: note: candidate: 'StringSumHelper::StringSumHelper(long long int)' <near match>
         StringSumHelper(long long num) :
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:390:9: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
mmsj300:313:24: error: invalid conversion from 'uint8_t*' {aka 'unsigned char*'} to 'long long int' [-fpermissive]
         Terminal.write((uint8_t*)"\e[" + String(bcor) +";" + String(fcor) + "m"); // background: defined, foreground: defined
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Arduino.h:165,
                 from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_152019\sketch\mmsj300.ino.cpp:1:
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:381:9: note: candidate: 'StringSumHelper::StringSumHelper(long unsigned int)' <near match>
         StringSumHelper(unsigned long num) :
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:381:9: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
mmsj300:313:24: error: invalid conversion from 'uint8_t*' {aka 'unsigned char*'} to 'long unsigned int' [-fpermissive]
         Terminal.write((uint8_t*)"\e[" + String(bcor) +";" + String(fcor) + "m"); // background: defined, foreground: defined
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Arduino.h:165,
                 from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_152019\sketch\mmsj300.ino.cpp:1:
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:378:9: note: candidate: 'StringSumHelper::StringSumHelper(long int)' <near match>
         StringSumHelper(long num) :
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:378:9: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
mmsj300:313:24: error: invalid conversion from 'uint8_t*' {aka 'unsigned char*'} to 'long int' [-fpermissive]
         Terminal.write((uint8_t*)"\e[" + String(bcor) +";" + String(fcor) + "m"); // background: defined, foreground: defined
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Arduino.h:165,
                 from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_152019\sketch\mmsj300.ino.cpp:1:
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:375:9: note: candidate: 'StringSumHelper::StringSumHelper(unsigned int)' <near match>
         StringSumHelper(unsigned int num) :
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:375:9: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
mmsj300:313:24: error: invalid conversion from 'uint8_t*' {aka 'unsigned char*'} to 'unsigned int' [-fpermissive]
         Terminal.write((uint8_t*)"\e[" + String(bcor) +";" + String(fcor) + "m"); // background: defined, foreground: defined
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Arduino.h:165,
                 from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_152019\sketch\mmsj300.ino.cpp:1:
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:372:9: note: candidate: 'StringSumHelper::StringSumHelper(int)' <near match>
         StringSumHelper(int num) :
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:372:9: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
mmsj300:313:24: error: invalid conversion from 'uint8_t*' {aka 'unsigned char*'} to 'int' [-fpermissive]
         Terminal.write((uint8_t*)"\e[" + String(bcor) +";" + String(fcor) + "m"); // background: defined, foreground: defined
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Arduino.h:165,
                 from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_152019\sketch\mmsj300.ino.cpp:1:
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:369:9: note: candidate: 'StringSumHelper::StringSumHelper(unsigned char)' <near match>
         StringSumHelper(unsigned char num) :
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:369:9: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
mmsj300:313:24: error: invalid conversion from 'uint8_t*' {aka 'unsigned char*'} to 'unsigned char' [-fpermissive]
         Terminal.write((uint8_t*)"\e[" + String(bcor) +";" + String(fcor) + "m"); // background: defined, foreground: defined
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Arduino.h:165,
                 from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_152019\sketch\mmsj300.ino.cpp:1:
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:366:9: note: candidate: 'StringSumHelper::StringSumHelper(char)' <near match>
         StringSumHelper(char c) :
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:366:9: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
mmsj300:313:24: error: invalid conversion from 'uint8_t*' {aka 'unsigned char*'} to 'char' [-fpermissive]
         Terminal.write((uint8_t*)"\e[" + String(bcor) +";" + String(fcor) + "m"); // background: defined, foreground: defined
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Arduino.h:165,
                 from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_152019\sketch\mmsj300.ino.cpp:1:
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:363:9: note: candidate: 'StringSumHelper::StringSumHelper(const char*)' <near match>
         StringSumHelper(const char *p) :
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:363:9: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
mmsj300:313:24: error: invalid conversion from 'uint8_t*' {aka 'unsigned char*'} to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
         Terminal.write((uint8_t*)"\e[" + String(bcor) +";" + String(fcor) + "m"); // background: defined, foreground: defined
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Arduino.h:165,
                 from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_152019\sketch\mmsj300.ino.cpp:1:
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:186:34: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'StringSumHelper& operator+(const StringSumHelper&, const String&)'
         friend StringSumHelper & operator +(const StringSumHelper &lhs, const String &rhs);
                                  ^~~~~~~~
mmsj300:314:52: error: conversion from 'uint8_t*' {aka 'unsigned char*'} to 'const StringSumHelper' is ambiguous
         Terminal.write((uint8_t*)"\e[" + String(vxx) + ";" + String(vyy) + "H");   // move cursor to x, y
                                                    ^
In file included from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Arduino.h:165,
                 from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_152019\sketch\mmsj300.ino.cpp:1:
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:393:9: note: candidate: 'StringSumHelper::StringSumHelper(long long unsigned int)' <near match>
         StringSumHelper(unsigned long long num) :
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:393:9: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
mmsj300:314:24: error: invalid conversion from 'uint8_t*' {aka 'unsigned char*'} to 'long long unsigned int' [-fpermissive]
         Terminal.write((uint8_t*)"\e[" + String(vxx) + ";" + String(vyy) + "H");   // move cursor to x, y
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Arduino.h:165,
                 from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_152019\sketch\mmsj300.ino.cpp:1:
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:390:9: note: candidate: 'StringSumHelper::StringSumHelper(long long int)' <near match>
         StringSumHelper(long long num) :
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:390:9: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
mmsj300:314:24: error: invalid conversion from 'uint8_t*' {aka 'unsigned char*'} to 'long long int' [-fpermissive]
         Terminal.write((uint8_t*)"\e[" + String(vxx) + ";" + String(vyy) + "H");   // move cursor to x, y
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Arduino.h:165,
                 from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_152019\sketch\mmsj300.ino.cpp:1:
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:381:9: note: candidate: 'StringSumHelper::StringSumHelper(long unsigned int)' <near match>
         StringSumHelper(unsigned long num) :
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:381:9: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
mmsj300:314:24: error: invalid conversion from 'uint8_t*' {aka 'unsigned char*'} to 'long unsigned int' [-fpermissive]
         Terminal.write((uint8_t*)"\e[" + String(vxx) + ";" + String(vyy) + "H");   // move cursor to x, y
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Arduino.h:165,
                 from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_152019\sketch\mmsj300.ino.cpp:1:
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:378:9: note: candidate: 'StringSumHelper::StringSumHelper(long int)' <near match>
         StringSumHelper(long num) :
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:378:9: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
mmsj300:314:24: error: invalid conversion from 'uint8_t*' {aka 'unsigned char*'} to 'long int' [-fpermissive]
         Terminal.write((uint8_t*)"\e[" + String(vxx) + ";" + String(vyy) + "H");   // move cursor to x, y
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Arduino.h:165,
                 from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_152019\sketch\mmsj300.ino.cpp:1:
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:375:9: note: candidate: 'StringSumHelper::StringSumHelper(unsigned int)' <near match>
         StringSumHelper(unsigned int num) :
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:375:9: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
mmsj300:314:24: error: invalid conversion from 'uint8_t*' {aka 'unsigned char*'} to 'unsigned int' [-fpermissive]
         Terminal.write((uint8_t*)"\e[" + String(vxx) + ";" + String(vyy) + "H");   // move cursor to x, y
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Arduino.h:165,
                 from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_152019\sketch\mmsj300.ino.cpp:1:
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:372:9: note: candidate: 'StringSumHelper::StringSumHelper(int)' <near match>
         StringSumHelper(int num) :
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:372:9: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
mmsj300:314:24: error: invalid conversion from 'uint8_t*' {aka 'unsigned char*'} to 'int' [-fpermissive]
         Terminal.write((uint8_t*)"\e[" + String(vxx) + ";" + String(vyy) + "H");   // move cursor to x, y
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Arduino.h:165,
                 from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_152019\sketch\mmsj300.ino.cpp:1:
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:369:9: note: candidate: 'StringSumHelper::StringSumHelper(unsigned char)' <near match>
         StringSumHelper(unsigned char num) :
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:369:9: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
mmsj300:314:24: error: invalid conversion from 'uint8_t*' {aka 'unsigned char*'} to 'unsigned char' [-fpermissive]
         Terminal.write((uint8_t*)"\e[" + String(vxx) + ";" + String(vyy) + "H");   // move cursor to x, y
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Arduino.h:165,
                 from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_152019\sketch\mmsj300.ino.cpp:1:
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:366:9: note: candidate: 'StringSumHelper::StringSumHelper(char)' <near match>
         StringSumHelper(char c) :
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:366:9: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
mmsj300:314:24: error: invalid conversion from 'uint8_t*' {aka 'unsigned char*'} to 'char' [-fpermissive]
         Terminal.write((uint8_t*)"\e[" + String(vxx) + ";" + String(vyy) + "H");   // move cursor to x, y
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Arduino.h:165,
                 from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_152019\sketch\mmsj300.ino.cpp:1:
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:363:9: note: candidate: 'StringSumHelper::StringSumHelper(const char*)' <near match>
         StringSumHelper(const char *p) :
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:363:9: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
mmsj300:314:24: error: invalid conversion from 'uint8_t*' {aka 'unsigned char*'} to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
         Terminal.write((uint8_t*)"\e[" + String(vxx) + ";" + String(vyy) + "H");   // move cursor to x, y
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Arduino.h:165,
                 from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_152019\sketch\mmsj300.ino.cpp:1:
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/WString.h:186:34: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'StringSumHelper& operator+(const StringSumHelper&, const String&)'
         friend StringSumHelper & operator +(const StringSumHelper &lhs, const String &rhs);
                                  ^~~~~~~~
mmsj300:334:72: error: no matching function for call to 'fabgl::Terminal::write(StringSumHelper&)'
           Terminal.write("\e[" + String(bcor) +";" + String(fcor) + "m"); // background: black, foreground: green
                                                                        ^
In file included from E:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\FabGL-master\src/fabgl.h:314,
                 from D:\Projetos\ESP32\MMSJ300\firmware\mmsj300\mmsj300.ino:27:
E:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\FabGL-master\src/terminal.h:1192:10: note: candidate: 'virtual size_t fabgl::Terminal::write(const uint8_t*, size_t)'
   size_t write(const uint8_t * buffer, size_t size);
          ^~~~~
E:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\FabGL-master\src/terminal.h:1192:10: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
E:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\FabGL-master\src/terminal.h:1201:10: note: candidate: 'virtual size_t fabgl::Terminal::write(uint8_t)'
   size_t write(uint8_t c);
          ^~~~~
E:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\FabGL-master\src/terminal.h:1201:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'StringSumHelper' to 'uint8_t' {aka 'unsigned char'}
E:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\FabGL-master\src/terminal.h:1209:8: note: candidate: 'void fabgl::Terminal::write(uint8_t, bool)'
   void write(uint8_t c, bool fromISR);
        ^~~~~
E:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\FabGL-master\src/terminal.h:1209:8: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
In file included from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Stream.h:26,
                 from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Arduino.h:166,
                 from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_152019\sketch\mmsj300.ino.cpp:1:
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Print.h:70:12: note: candidate: 'size_t Print::write(const char*, size_t)'
     size_t write(const char *buffer, size_t size)
            ^~~~~
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Print.h:70:12: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Print.h:62:12: note: candidate: 'size_t Print::write(const char*)'
     size_t write(const char *str)
            ^~~~~
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Print.h:62:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'StringSumHelper' to 'const char*'
mmsj300:335:71: error: no matching function for call to 'fabgl::Terminal::write(StringSumHelper&)'
           Terminal.write("\e[" + String(vxx) + ";" + String(vyy) + "H");   // move cursor
                                                                       ^
In file included from E:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\FabGL-master\src/fabgl.h:314,
                 from D:\Projetos\ESP32\MMSJ300\firmware\mmsj300\mmsj300.ino:27:
E:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\FabGL-master\src/terminal.h:1192:10: note: candidate: 'virtual size_t fabgl::Terminal::write(const uint8_t*, size_t)'
   size_t write(const uint8_t * buffer, size_t size);
          ^~~~~
E:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\FabGL-master\src/terminal.h:1192:10: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
E:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\FabGL-master\src/terminal.h:1201:10: note: candidate: 'virtual size_t fabgl::Terminal::write(uint8_t)'
   size_t write(uint8_t c);
          ^~~~~
E:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\FabGL-master\src/terminal.h:1201:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'StringSumHelper' to 'uint8_t' {aka 'unsigned char'}
E:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\FabGL-master\src/terminal.h:1209:8: note: candidate: 'void fabgl::Terminal::write(uint8_t, bool)'
   void write(uint8_t c, bool fromISR);
        ^~~~~
E:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\FabGL-master\src/terminal.h:1209:8: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
In file included from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Stream.h:26,
                 from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Arduino.h:166,
                 from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_152019\sketch\mmsj300.ino.cpp:1:
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Print.h:70:12: note: candidate: 'size_t Print::write(const char*, size_t)'
     size_t write(const char *buffer, size_t size)
            ^~~~~
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Print.h:70:12: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Print.h:62:12: note: candidate: 'size_t Print::write(const char*)'
     size_t write(const char *str)
            ^~~~~
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Print.h:62:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'StringSumHelper' to 'const char*'
mmsj300:343:72: error: no matching function for call to 'fabgl::Terminal::write(StringSumHelper&)'
           Terminal.write("\e[" + String(fcor) +";" + String(bcor) + "m"); // background: black, foreground: green
                                                                        ^
In file included from E:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\FabGL-master\src/fabgl.h:314,
                 from D:\Projetos\ESP32\MMSJ300\firmware\mmsj300\mmsj300.ino:27:
E:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\FabGL-master\src/terminal.h:1192:10: note: candidate: 'virtual size_t fabgl::Terminal::write(const uint8_t*, size_t)'
   size_t write(const uint8_t * buffer, size_t size);
          ^~~~~
E:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\FabGL-master\src/terminal.h:1192:10: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
E:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\FabGL-master\src/terminal.h:1201:10: note: candidate: 'virtual size_t fabgl::Terminal::write(uint8_t)'
   size_t write(uint8_t c);
          ^~~~~
E:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\FabGL-master\src/terminal.h:1201:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'StringSumHelper' to 'uint8_t' {aka 'unsigned char'}
E:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\FabGL-master\src/terminal.h:1209:8: note: candidate: 'void fabgl::Terminal::write(uint8_t, bool)'
   void write(uint8_t c, bool fromISR);
        ^~~~~
E:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\FabGL-master\src/terminal.h:1209:8: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
In file included from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Stream.h:26,
                 from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Arduino.h:166,
                 from C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_152019\sketch\mmsj300.ino.cpp:1:
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Print.h:70:12: note: candidate: 'size_t Print::write(const char*, size_t)'
     size_t write(const char *buffer, size_t size)
            ^~~~~
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Print.h:70:12: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Print.h:62:12: note: candidate: 'size_t Print::write(const char*)'
     size_t write(const char *str)
            ^~~~~
C:\Users\moahr\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32/Print.h:62:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'StringSumHelper' to 'const char*'
mmsj300:344:71: error: no matching function for call to 'fabgl::Terminal::write(StringSumHelper&)'
           Terminal.write("\e[" + String(vxx) + ";" + String(vyy) + "H");   // move cursor
                                                                       ^
In file included from E:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\FabGL-master\src/fabgl.h:314,
                 from D:\Projetos\ESP32\MMSJ300\firmware\mmsj300\mmsj300.ino:27:
E:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\FabGL-master\src/terminal.h:1192:10: note: candidate: 'virtual size_t fabgl::Terminal::write(const uint8_t*, size_t)'
   size_t write(const uint8_t * buffer, size_t size);
          ^~~~~
E:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\FabGL-master\
```

Comment: `String("\e[") + String(bcor) + ...` (and the same for all literal strings)?

Comment: Posted complete error (almost, because is too big to put in this question).

Comment: String("\e[") + String(bcor) + ... (and the same for all literal strings)? – 
Some programmer dude, sadly not... same error... but thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You have *two* problems:

The first is that you should not cast any literal string. The `StringSumHelper` class have a `const char *` constructor that could be used, and literal strings will be converted to a `const char *` by default.

So doing e.g.

```
Terminal.write("\e[" + String(bcor) +";" + String(fcor) + "m"); // background: defined, foreground: defined
```

should work fine.

---

The second problem is that there's no proper `Terminal::write` function to use. You should declare (and define) it to use a `String` argument:

```
size_t Terminal::write(const String& string)
```

You could create this function as an overload that calls the variant with a pointer and a size:

```
size_t Terminal::write(const String& string)
{
    return write(static_cast<const uint8_t*>(string.c_str()), string.length());
}
```

Comment: I have tried this:
Terminal.write("\e[" + String(bcor) +";" + String(fcor) + "m");
And same error.

The second problem, I cant modify, is just inside library. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: If you can't modify `Terminal`, then you have to put a message in a local variable and call `Terminal.write(string.c_str(), string.length());`

Answer (score 1):

If `Terminal` inherits `Print`, this will work

```
Terminal.write(("\e[" + String(bcor) +";" + String(fcor) + "m").c_str());
```

Otherwise you have to put a message in a local variable

```
auto string = "\e[" + String(bcor) +";" + String(fcor) + "m";
Terminal.write(static_cast<const uint8_t*>(string.c_str()), string.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use `.c_str()` like this:

```cpp
// background: defined, foreground: defined
Terminal.write(("\e[" + String(bcor) +";" + String(fcor) + "m").c_str());
```

I do not like to use `c_str()`, but the only unique solution was this... until now.

Comment: Why do you not like to use `c_str()` to convert a string to a char array for a function that expects one? Why does your solution need to be unique?